# Angular 2 routing modules interaction

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-modules

I have 3 modules: SimpleCalculations, FunnyCalculations, OtherCalculations.
Each of them has `routing.module.ts` file, where I define their child routes and other stuff.

I want to have MainCalculation module, which child routes wold be taken from modules I've already told. 
And for example I'd add common `CanActivate` guard to all routes in these modules.

What the right way to do it? I don't want to mess all this routes in one file.

Comment: My related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020569/angular2-routing-import-submodule-with-routing-making-it-prefixed