# Adding a route prefix for an outside module's routes?

Tags: javascript, angular

In my `app.module.ts` file  , I import (eagerly)  `LoginModule` which has *its own routing module* (`login-routing.module.ts` - *let's say I can't change it*)

I also import  another routing module (`AppRoutingModule` - which deals with all lazy modules) .

<kbd>`app.module.ts:`</kbd>

```
    @NgModule({
                  bootstrap   : [AppComponent],
                  imports     : [
                      ...
                      LoginModule,
                      AppRoutingModule
                      ...
                  ]...
```

The `login-routing.module.ts` file has its own routing :

<kbd>`login-routing.module.ts :`</kbd>

```
  const LoginRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path     : 'welcome',
        component: WelcomeComponent
    },
    {
        path     : 'loginSms',
        component: LoginSmsComponent
    },
    {
        path     : 'loginPassword',
        component: LoginPasswordComponent
    },
    {
        path     : 'passwordExpired',
        component: PasswordExpiredComponent
    }
];


@NgModule({
            ...
          })
export class LoginRoutingModule
    {
    }
```

And `AppRoutingModule` has :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    /* {    path      : "",    redirectTo: "/welcome",    pathMatch : "full"},*/
    {
        path    : 'app',
        children: [
            {
                path        : "home",
                loadChildren: "~/modules/home/home.module#HomeModule"
            },
            {
                path        : "payments",
                loadChildren: "~/modules/payments/payments.module#PaymentsModule"
            }
        ]
    }
 ...
```

Please notice that I've used ComponentLess route with prefix `app` just to organize routes.

**So where is the problem?**

I want to add the Login routes to **"app routes"** , so that I will access login routes as : 
`app/login/...`

In other words - now - `AppRoutingModule` should be :

```
  path    : 'app',
            children: [
                {
                    path        : "home",
                    loadChildren: "~/modules/home/home.module#HomeModule"
                },
                {
                    path        : "payments",
                    loadChildren: "~/modules/payments/payments.module#PaymentsModule"
                },
                {
                    path        : "login",
                     //but how o I load all `login-routing.module.ts` routes here ?

                },

            ]
```

But `LoginModule` should be eager loaded and not lazy loaded , so I can't use `loadChildern`.

**Question:**

In short , how can I access the login module routes as :

`app/login/loginPassword`

instead of

`/loginPassword`

?

Comment: If the real reason for doing it this way, is to have the LoginModule eagerly loaded, you can also use the `preloadingStrategy` of the router

Comment: @PierreDuc Oh. So you mean to add it as if it was lazy ( `loadChildren`) , and just to add the `preloadingStrategy ` hint ?

Comment: Exactly, want me to post an example?

Comment: @PierreDuc No thanks. I got it. BTW I saw this `answer` [here also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41021387/859154) - but he loaded only the array routes and not the  route **module** . I don't use in my app -  plain routes array. I use routing **modules** everywhere.

Comment: That's also possible, the main difference will be that your initial bundle on load will be bigger if you do it that way

Comment: @PierreDuc mmmm Are you sure that `PreloadAllModules`  === as if I was loading it like I did ? becuase they say : ["as quickly as possible"](https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadAllModules)

Comment: `PreloadAllModules` will load all your lazy modules. That's not what you want. If you want, when the application is loaded, to load the login module bundle, you have to use a custom preloading strategy. If you want the LoginModule to be part of your initial bundle, then you just add the routes from the module to the app module (like in the other question)

Comment: @PierreDuc But I can't load the login routes array just like that..  The Login [routes are in a module](https://i.imgur.com/NGfl8Gx.jpg) . I can't just import this array. it is exported  along with the `LoginRoutingModule`

Comment: You cannot use the `LoginRoutingModule` with the second option :) can't see a way to make it work. You should just import the routes in your `AppRoutingModule` and inside your `LoginModule` remove the `LoginRoutingModule`. And if that's not an option, you should use a custom preloadingStrategy

Comment: @PierreDuc Thank you  (sad)

Comment: Don't be sad, it's gonna be okay

Answer (score 0):

did you add 
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' } like this in app.module

Comment: This will not help . the issue is not the inital redirection. but the whole login routes should be prefixed from now on. Also  - this should be a comment